# How to create a new model (kind) in google cloud Datastore

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Datastore(not NDB) for my project.

python2.7 and Django.

I want to create a new model, lets say Tag model.

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    feature = ndb.StringProperty(default='')
```

I have added property to a model many times, but not yet created new model.

My question is when I have changed model schema in Django for my another project using mySQL, I always executed manage.py migrate.

Do I have to execute the migration command for Datastore as well?

Or just defining the model is all I have to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike SQL databases like MySQL, Cloud Datastore doesn't require you to create kinds (similar to tables) in advance. Other than defining it in your code, no admin steps are required to create the kind.

When you write the first entity of that kind, it's created implicitly for you.

You can even query for kinds that don't exist yet without an error, you'll just get no entities back:

[image: Example GQL statement on a kind that doesn't exist, shows message of "No entities matched this query"]

Comment: Thanks for the example. Actually I want to define the model scheme in models.py in advance like the Tag class above. In that case, I don't need to execute the command "python manage.py migrate" in order to create a tag table(kind), neither?

Comment: Why do you think you do?

Comment: Yeah right. I was confused with RDB... Migration command is for RDB.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to migrate, except if you are using the same database from the another project. Anyway if you type migrate it will create the tables from your models but if you are working with a existing database nothing is going to happen

Comment: Thanks! I think I was confused with RDB and NoSQL concept. Migrate command is for creating tables or updating field, right? I supposed such operations as creating tables or updating fields is not necessary for schemaless DB like cloud datastore.

Comment: You just can accept one answer, but you can voteup both

Comment: Got it! Will do it!